# How can I rebuild my Basset collections?

Tags: laravel-4

If I use basset:rebuil:

```
php artisan basset:build
```

It tells that it is not required but the file is not there:
[public] Stylesheets build was not required for collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rebuild all your collections in Basset, but first you need to delete basset manifest:

```
php artisan basset --delete-manifest
```

Then to rebuild all your collections from basset config as usual:

```
php artisan basset:build
```

To build a particular collection you can give its name:

```
php artisan basset:build admin
```

However, doing this Basset throws an error, stating it cannot read the rebuilt collection.json file in app/storage/meta. You can get around this, by modifying perms manually through the terminal:

```
chmod -R 777 app/storage/meta
```

Comment: should i give 777 to /public/assets/ also?

Comment: To prevent Basset error you only need to give 777 permissions to app/storage/data where Bassets saves collections.json with references to final resources like CSS or JS files.